# Is it possible to create a page that shows only a specific post type with its own url?

Tags: templating, entry-type, category

I have a website with a shop section with the following URL structure: `homepage/shop/category/the-product`.

I would like to add a page after the category to filter between post types within that category, and I want to be able to access it through the entry type slug in the URL.

I also need to change the template to match the Entry Type.

If this is possible, how do I do it?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly possible and simple too :)

First in the CP go to:

```
Category->Settings
```

You'll want to set your `Category URL formats` and `Category Template` to reflect your URL scheme and desired location of your template file.

Then create an _entry template in the directory you specified above for example `/categories/_entry.twig`

When you head to the URL above your template will load with an entry variable that reflects whichever category you are browsing to.

In the `_entry` template to get all the entries related to the current category:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo( entry ) %}
```

(note this will default to 100 entries if you want more append `.limit(101)` etc. or `.limit(null)` to get them all.

and finally to load a layout based on the entry.type simply:

```
{% include ["_layouts/types/" ~ entry.type, "_layouts/types/default"] %}
```

where the default layout is for all entries that don't need any special layout.